# Updating firestore from vue, then reload page to get updated data (not working)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I would like to :

- get an array from my current firestore
- update the array
- update the firestore with the new array
- reload the page with the new updated information.

```js
db.collection("partners").doc(uid).get().then(doc => {
        curarr = doc.data().donation_goal
        curarr[curmonth] = newgoal;
      }).then(() => {
        alert(curarr)
        db.collection("partners").doc(uid).update({
          "donation_goal": curarr
        });
      }).then(() => {
        location.reload(true);
      })
```

The weird thing is that is i were to comment out `location.reload(true);`
and manually refresh the page, it works.
However, adding `location.reload(true)` does not update my database at all.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've played around and found the issue. It was about where i place then then clause.

You can find the updated answer below:

```
db.collection("partners").doc(uid).get().then(doc => {
    curarr = doc.data().donation_goal
    curarr[curmonth] = newgoal;
    db.collection("partners").doc(uid).update({
        "donation_goal": curarr
    }).then(() => {
        location.reload(true);
    });
})
```